# divs placement and display

Tags: css, forms, html

I'm trying to create a form with this formatting style:

```
label a
[input text] SUBMIT

label b
[select]

label c
label from [input text] label to [input texŧ] SUBMIT
```

This is my html with css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    form {
        width:460px;
    }
    form label {
        font-size:12px;
        color:#666;
        cursor:auto !important;
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        padding:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        width:370px;
        color:#333;
        font-size:14px;    
    }

    form select {
        padding:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:26px;
        width:370px;
        color:#333;
        font-size:12px;
        border:solid 1px #ccc;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    form input[type=submit] {
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
        background: url("/mini_glass.png") no-repeat scroll 3px 3px transparent;
        border:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

</style>

<div class="margin_top_20">
    <form action="">
        <div>        
            <div id="A">
                <label>a</label>
                <input name="q" value="" type="text">  
                <input value="" type="submit">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="B">
            <label>b</label>
            <select></select>
        </div>

        <div id="C">
            <label>c</label>
            <div id="D">
                <label>from</label>
                <input name="from" value="" type="text" style="width:50px">

                <label>to</label>
                <input name="to" value="" type="text" style="width:50px">
                <input value="" type="submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that I should set properties like position or float but I don't understand how. Should I use the float:left property for some divs? The way that property works is not very clear to me.

Comment: your form is pretty much laid out as you wanted, you just need a `<br />` after your labels a, b and c

Comment: If you want the different submits to only submit their respective fields, you'll need to use multiple `<form>` elements.

Comment: I would also suggest that you learn the difference between `block`, `inline` and `inline-block` elements and then you'll have a better understanding of when you need to `float` an element

Comment: thank YOU @MadaraUchiha, great observation, I'll use two forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your form and CSS and here is the [Working Solution as per the format that you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/N59KL/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="margin_top_20">
    <form action="">
        <div>        
            <div id="A">
                <label>a</label>
                <input name="q" value="" type="text">  
                <input value="submit" type="button">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="B">
            <label>b</label>
            <select></select>
        </div>

        <div id="C">
            <label>c</label>
            <div id="D">
                <span>from</span>
                <input name="from" value="" type="text" style="width:50px">

                <span>to</span>
                <input name="to" value="" type="text" style="width:50px">
                <input value="submit" type="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
 form {
        width:460px;
    }
    form label {
        font-size:12px;
        color:#666;
        cursor:auto !important;
    display:block;
    }

    span{
        font-size:12px;
        color:#666;
        cursor:auto !important;
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        padding:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        width:370px;
        color:#333;
        font-size:14px;    
    }

    form select {
        padding:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:26px;
        width:370px;
        color:#333;
        font-size:12px;
        border:solid 1px #ccc;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    form input[type=submit] {
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
        background: url("/mini_glass.png") no-repeat scroll 3px 3px transparent;
        border:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

You just needed to add a `display:block;` for the `form label` and a `<span>` tag for `from` and `to` and I changed input type from `submit` to `button` and valued as `submit`. You can change and style it as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. this works great on jsFiddle but not on my preview, and I have no idea why.

Comment: What are you using for preview? - @tonydanza. I checked the code in dreamweaver preview and also on browsers, it works fine.

Comment: I'm using firefox but working on cq5. Only problem is with the select input type, it's still positioned after the label.

Comment: Change `display:block;` in `form label` css to `display:table-cell;`.

Comment: still not working :( thanks anyway

Comment: Delete your Firefox cache and then check. - @tonydanza

Comment: Anyways, you have the solution for your issue, but you need to figure out with any css or other things that is not allowing it to function the way it is functioning on my end as well as the jsfiddle. - @tonydanza

Comment: you're right. I think the problem is with my form width, which is set to 460px.

Answer (score 1):

Just add rules specific to the labels in `div` A and `div` B

`#A label, #B label { display:block}`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/emTKJ/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you want to position a group of element, you should wrapped it with div element and style it. With some element have similar style, add it with the same class. Shouldn't set width of form, just wrap the content inside it with a div and set style for it. I fixed your code here. [See full demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/rhWsr/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="margin_top_20">
    <form action="">
        <div class="line">
            <div id="A">
                <div>
                    <label>Lable A</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="q" value="" type="text" />
                    <input value="submit button" type="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line" id="B">
            <div><label>Label b</label></div>
            <div><select></select></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line" id="C">
            <div><label>Label c</label></div>
            <div id="D">
                <label>from</label>
                <input name="from" value="" type="text" style="width:50px" />
                <label>to</label>
                <input name="to" value="" type="text" style="width:50px" />
                <input value="submit button" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
form {
}
.line{
    padding-top:5px;
}
form label {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666;
    cursor:auto !important;
}
form input[type=text] {
    padding:5px;
    width:370px;
    color:#333;
    font-size:14px;
}
form select {
    padding:5px;
    width:370px;
    color:#333;
    font-size:12px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}
form input[type=submit] {
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```